# "Suspected" VS "had suspected" VS "had been suspecting"

Tags: tense, past-tense

> **For a long time** many scientists **suspected** that koalas were so lethargic because the compounds in eucalyptus leaves kept the cute little animals in a drugged­out state. But more recent research has shown that the leaves are simply so low in nutrients that koalas have almost no energy.

Can I use **had suspected** or **had been suspecting** instead of **suspected**? To me, it seems possible because "For a long time", the action of the verb was maintained for a certain duration of time.

Do the two of them have same meaning in the context above?

Comment: You don't normally use the verb "suspect" in the progressive form. It's either *We suspect that X is false* or *We suspected that X was/is false* NOT "we are/were suspecting..."

Answer (score 2):

All three are pretty much equal in meaning, but "had suspected" would be the preferred choice here, since it emphasises that this has now changed.

Comment: +1 Worth noting that though "had been suspecting" is "equal in meaning", it's not natural, to the point I suspect it's not grammatical.